# Insert Data else Update FROM a CSV file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, insert-update, sql-job

I am currently using an SQL job to import the contents of a CSV file (BULK INSERT). I use a LEFT JOIN statement to check if there are duplicates and to not insert them if any are found. However, I would like to instead UPDATE a column if their are duplicates. 
Here are the fileds of my CSV file: 
`|UserType|Lname|Fname|Mname|ContactNo|Email|Password|Balance|Status`

Here is my LEFT JOIN statement.

```
INSERT INTO tblAccount
SELECT CSVTable.AccountID,
CSVTable.UserType,
CSVTable.Lname,
CSVTable.Fname,
CSVTable.Mname,
CSVTable.ContactNo,
CSVTable.Email,
CSVTable.Password,
CSVTable.EPurseBalance,
CSVTable.AccountStatus
FROM CSVTable
       LEFT JOIN tblAccount 
         ON CSVTable.AccountID = tblAccount.AccountID
WHERE tblAccount.AccountID  IS NULL
```

I would like to `UPDATE` existing records if duplicates are found. Let's say a user's `AccountStatus`. If a user is already on the Accounts table BUT his account was deactivated, I would like to update not the entire row but only the `AccountStatus` column.

My current statement discards duplicate entries regardless if some columns are different. How can I insert if data is non existent but update a column if its already existing?

Any efforts to answer my question will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
I tried the MERGE command. Here is my statement:

```
MERGE 
   tblAccount AS target
USING 
   CSVTable AS source
ON 
   target.AccountID = source.AccountID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
INSERT INTO tblAccount
SELECT CSVTable.AccountID,
        CSVTable.UserType,
        CSVTable.Lname,
        CSVTable.Fname,
        CSVTable.Mname,
        CSVTable.Address,
        CSVTable.Gender,
        CSVTable.Birthdate,
        CSVTable.ContactNo,
        CSVTable.Email,
        CSVTable.Password,
        CSVTable.EPurseBalance,
        CSVTable.AccountStatus
FROM CSVTable
       LEFT JOIN tblAccount 
         ON CSVTable.AccountID = tblAccount.AccountID
WHERE tblAccount.AccountID  IS NULL



WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET tblAccount.AccountStatus = CSVTable.AccountStatus
;
```

This doesn't work and SQL server throws me errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.
```

I tried inserting my LEFT JOIN statement in my MERGE but to no avail. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) instruction?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008. Yes, I tried the merge command but I get errors.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below link will help you

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: This answer will become useless if that link ever goes dead.